# Using an Object in Mobile App c#

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a simple mobile app game using c# and Xamarin.Forms and have gotten stuck trying to use an object class called Player.

```
class Player
    {
        private int level;

     public int Level
     {
        get { return Level; }
        set { Level = value; }
     }

     public Player() 
     {  //variables initialized
         this.Level = 1;}
}
```

The ContentPage that creates the UI also creates an instance of Player, but when any property in Player is accessed, the app crashes.

Right now I have Player player as a data member in BasePage (the ContentPage class), and the accessing of player happens when the user presses a button:

```
class BasePage : ContentPage
    {
        private Player player;

        public BasePage()            {
             player= new Player();
            //stuff...
            var btnPlayer = new Button
            {
                Text = "YOU"
            };
            btnPlayer.Clicked += (o, e) =>
            {
                //change text in lblMessage
                lblMessage.Text = "Your level: " + player.Level;
            };
       //stuff is added to screen, not relevant
   }
```

How should I be creating player so it doesn't crash? I've been checking out other questions on here and I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for (I've tried binding the object as well, but I might not be doing it correctly).

Comment: What error are you getting when it crashes?

Comment: *but when any property in Player is accessed, the app crashes.* You're lying.  I don't see anything in your question that proves the application is crashing, such as exception details.  Those exception details would tell you EXACTLY what is going on.  For example, it could say that you had a StackOverflowException on the line "return Level;".  Which is exactly what it did say... if it actually happened.  Which it didn't, as far as I can tell.  In future, when you have a question about why your application crashes, *capture the exception details and READ them, then add them to your question.*

Comment: I am using an emulator and it does not create an exception but rather the app just stops, and the program stops entirely. But thank you for pointing out I forgot to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code causes an infinitely recursive loop - the public `Level` (capital 'L') property is returning the value of the public Level property, which causes it to call the 'get' again, repeatedly

```
public int Level
{
  get { return Level; }
  set { Level = value; }
}
```

instead you should use the private member variable `level` (small 'l')

```
public int Level
{
  get { return level; }
  set { level = value; }
}
```

You could also do this, which will allow C# to create the property for you without explicitly creating a private variable.

```
public int Level { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It's funny how one letter can slip by and create such a problem.